# Fourier Series Trig Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need assistance finding the fourier series for the following function:

$$  f(x)=3\cos^2(5x) $$

I know that

$$ a_0={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi 3\cos^2(5x)\,dx={3 \over 2}   $$

and

$$ b_n={1\over \pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi 3\cos^2(5x)\sin(nx)\,dx=0   $$

I'm having difficulty calculating $a_n$ because I keep getting zero.

$$ a_n={1\over \pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi 3\cos^2(5x)\cos(nx)\,dx=?   $$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My mistake. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling the identity

> $$ \cos(2t) = 2\cos(t)^2-1 $$

which gives us the desired Fourier series

> $$ 3\cos(5x)^2= \frac{3}{2}( 1+\cos(10 x) ). $$

**Added:** to get $a_n$ note that the function is even so you can do the following

> $$ a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 3\cos(5x)^2 \cos(nx) dx = \frac{6}{\pi}\,{\frac {\sin \left( \pi \,n \right)  \left( {n}^{2}-50 \right) }{n
>  \left( {n}^{2}-100 \right) }}
> . $$

Comment: How do I evaluate $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi (1+cos(10x))cos(nx)dx$

Comment: @user106292: You do need to make these calculations instead you can use the trick I gave you. However you can expand the integral and you need to use another identities which is $\cos(A\pm B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)\mp \sin(A)\sin(B)$.

Comment: I'm not following. I can use ${3 \over 2}*(1+cos(10x))$ but I still need to evaluate that integral to find $a_n$

Comment: @user106292: $ \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\cos(10 x) ) $ is the desired Fourier series. It is a short cut for finding it in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user106292: I can post the result of the integral $a_n$ to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos^2(2x) = \frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}$, and you don't need to do any integration.

Comment: Right. So when i divide it up into two integrals and evaluate I keep getting 0.

Comment: Can you explain more why "you don't need to do any integration"?

Comment: What is the Taylor series of the function $f(x) = 5x + 9x^2 + 6x^{10}$? Okay, now what is the Fourier series of $\cos(3x) + 6\sin(x)$? Okay, now what is the Fourier series of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$?

Comment: The point is that an expression like $\sin(9x)$ is already a Fourier series. Its Fourier series is just itself.

Answer (score 0):

$$u=5x\implies \frac{du}5=dx\implies$$

$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^25x\,dx=\frac15\int\limits_{-5\pi}^{5\pi}\cos^2u\,du=\frac15\left.\frac{u+\cos u\sin u}2\right|_{-5\pi}^{5\pi}=\pi\neq 0$$

Comment: Thanks. I actually corrected that in my question a few minutes ago.